# Incorrect Value in Register After Run LC3 Assembly

Tags: assembly, computer-science, low-level, lc3, lc3-trap

I am creating an LC3 program to display sum and count of positive and negative numbers but when I run the program in the Simulate program - I look at R5 which is suppose to hold the sum of positive numbers only shows the first +ve number added. My code is below - any suggestions new to using lc3/assembly

```
.ORIG x3000


and r1, r1,#0 ; clear r1
and r2, r2, #0 ; neg counter amount of negative numbers
and r3, r3, #0 ; positive counter amount of pos numbers
and r4, r4, #0; negative sum
and r5,r5, #0; positive sum
and r6,r6,#0; clear register


LEA R1, DATA



loop            
        ldr r6, r1, #0
        BRn negativecountm ;if negative go to branch to ncount method
        BRp positivecountm ;if positive go to branch to pcount method
        BRz Escape ;if 0 encountered program done go to escape method


negativecountm 
        add r2, r2, #1 ; increment count for neg numbers
        add r4, r4, r6 ; sum of neg number
        add r1, r1,#1 ; increment pointer to point to next number in data
        BRp loop ; go back to original loop

positivecountm 
        add r3, r3, #1 ; increment count for positive num
        add r5, r5, r6; sum of +ve num
        add r1, r1, #1 ; increment pointer to point to next num in data
        BRn loop;


Escape  
        ST r2, negativecount ;
        ST r3, positivecount;
        ST r5, positivesum;
        ST r4, negativesum;
        TRAP x25 ;


   DATA     .Fill 1244
            .Fill -23
            .Fill 17
            .Fill 6
            .Fill -12
            .Fill 0


negativecount .BLKW 1
positivecount .BLKW 1
positivesum .BLKW 1
negativesum .BLKW 1


.END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BRp loop ; go back to original loop
[...]
BRn loop;
```

Both of these branch statements are not quite correct.  Remember that the condition codes are set anytime an instruction writes to a register (that is LD,LEA,LDR,LDI,ADD,AND,NOT)

The condition codes are being set when you do

```
add r1, r1, #1 ; increment pointer to point to next num in data
```

In the positive number case surely r1 will not contain a negative value after that ADD instruction.

Simply changing your branches to be an unconditional branch would fix it.

So instead of BRn/p simply saying

```
BR loop
```

Will do the trick.